# perl + add warn massage in perl one liner code

Tags: linux, perl, shell, ksh

I have perl one liner code  that rename the names of files/directories

code:

```
find /tmp -name "*$NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE*" -exec /tmp/rename.pl  's/\Q$ENV{NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE}\E/$1$ENV{NEW_NAME}$2/' {} +
```

I want to add print message ( warn )  ,  to my code in order to print which file/directory will be change

so I add the line:

```
       && warn "Rename file - [$ENV{$NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE}"'
```

so finaly the update code will be:

```
find /tmp -name "*$NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE*" -exec /tmp/rename.pl  's/\Q$ENV{NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE}\E/$1$ENV{NEW_NAME}$2/ {} + && warn "Rename file - [$ENV{$NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE}"'
```

when I run the perl one liner I get the follwoing error message:

```
    find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

please advice what I need to fix/update in my code ?

.
.
.
.
.

full example ( before I add the warn "........." )

```
cd /tmp
touch orig-name
touch new-name
export NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE=orig-name
export NEW_NAME=new-name



find /tmp -name "*$NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE*" -exec /tmp/rename.pl  's/\Q$ENV{NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE}\E/$1$ENV{NEW_NAME}$2/' {} +

ls | grep new-name
new-name



more /tmp/rename.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# rename script examples from lwall:
#       rename 's/\.orig$//' *.orig
#       rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/ unless /^Make/' *
#       rename '$_ .= ".bad"' *.f
#       rename 'print "$_: "; s/foo/bar/ if <stdin> =~ /^y/i' *

$op = shift;
for (@ARGV) {
$was = $_;
eval $op;
die $@ if $@;
rename($was,$_) unless $was eq $_;
```

Comment: Is that a `+` at the end of the `find`?  Should it not be `\;`?

Comment: This is a dreadful misuse of Perl. Why is that different from `mv $NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE $NEW_NAME`?

Comment: I need to use the \Q and \E in order to get exactly match of the file/dir and perl is the best way to use it (Regular expressions) , I not know other option ,

Comment: the other point is that I need to perform a recursive search for files/dirs ( /tmp is only example )

Comment: other example: find /tmp  -name "*$NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE*" -exec perl -e '$op=shift;for(@ARGV){$was=$_;eval$op;die$@if$@;rename$was,$_ unless$was eq$_}'   's/(?<![\d.])\Q$ENV{NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE}\E(?=\.(?:1?\d?\d|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?!\d))/$ENV{NEW_NAME}/g' {} +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use autodie;
for (@ARGV) {
  rename $_, $_ =~ s/\Q$ENV{ORIGNAME}\E/$ENV{DESTNAME}/r
    and warn "Rename file - [$_]\n";
}
```

Or if you're on CentOS, and can't use e.g. cPanel's newer perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
for (@ARGV) {
  (my $new = $_) =~ s/\Q$ENV{ORIGNAME}\E/$ENV{DESTNAME}/
    and warn "Rename file - [$_]\n";
  rename $_, $new or die "Rename of ``$_'' to ``$new'' failed: $!";
}
```

Or if you really need arbitrary Perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
my $op = shift;
for (@ARGV) {
  my $old = $_;
  eval $op; die $@ if $@;
  next if $old eq $_;
  rename $old, $_ and warn "Rename file - [$old]\n"
}
```

Mind the subtle differences.

In the first two cases, adjust your `find` appropriately:

```
find /tmp -name "*$ORIGNAME*" -exec /tmp/rename.pl {} +
```

It's not significant that my environment variables are less painful.

By the way, your error was not a Perl one so much as a *very obvious* `find` error.  `find` and especially `find` with `-exec` is dangerous, yo: have someone who knows what they're doing take a look at your script before you run it.

Comment: I think the best choice is option 2 ( option 1 with "autodie"  ,and I dont have this module in my perl version )

Comment: @Eytan, it's dangerous in the usual sense: it's very easy to break things and lose data with it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the whole thing in Perl?

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use 5.12.0;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use File::Find;
use Getopt::Long;
```

A little break here...

The [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) is a standard Perl module that will allow you to do the file find internally inside of Perl.  The [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.pm) is a nice little command that parses the command line arguments for you. Both of these are part of Perl's standard package, and there is absolutely no reason not to use them.

And now, back to our program in progress.

```
my ($from, $to, $dir);

my $usage =<<USAGE;
  find_and_rename.pl -from <from> -to <to> -dir <dir>
USAGE

GetOptions {
    'from=s'     => $from,
    'to=s'       => $to,
    'dir=s'      => $dir,
} or die ($usage\n);

if ( not $from or not $to or not $dir ) {
   die ($usage\n);
}
```

Another break... See how nicely `Getopt::Long` parses the command line? A single function `GetOptions` does all of the parsing for you. All you need to do is verify the input. (And, GetOptions could even do that for you too!). Take a look at [Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org) and look at the various Modules that are included in almost any installation of Perl. They're just as much as the Perl language as commands such as `pop` or `push`, and these modules can make programming in Perl much, much easier.

```
my @files_found;
find ( sub {
       return unless /$from/;
       @files_found, $File::Find::name;
     }, $dir);

for my $file ( @files_found ) {
   (here be dragons...)
   rename $file, $to_name;
}
```

This is a rough outline of your program. It all depends upon what you really want to accomplish, but it does show how you can do everything in a single program rather than relying upon using find, and then your Perl script embedded in a find. All without all that much extra work.

You probably want to add a few more features (like something telling you what each file was renamed to, and maybe include a `-dry-run` option that you could use to just see what the results would look like without renaming anything.

I prefer to use `find` to fill in a list of file names that I can operate on later. There's no reason why that couldn't be included in the find. I also like embedding my subroutine directly into my `find` command. However:

```
find ( sub {
       return unless /$from/;
       @files_found, $File::Find::name;
     }, $dir);
```

is equivalent to:

```
find ( \&wanted, $dir);

sub wanted {
   return unless /$from/;
   @files_found, $File::Find::name;
}
```

which might make it easier for you to understand.

To use your program, you'd simply do this:

```
$ find_and_replace.pl -dir . -from REPLACE_THIS -to with_this
```

---

### AND NOW A SPECIAL BONUS OFFER!

Save the best for last. There's a command called `find2perl` which will convert your Unix Find command into a Perl script. And, the best part: It's already on your system:

```
$ find2perl find /tmp -name "*$NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE*" -exec /tmp/rename.pl \;

#! /usr/bin/perl -w
    eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
        if 0; #$running_under_some_shell

use strict;
use File::Find ();

# Set the variable $File::Find::dont_use_nlink if you're using AFS,
# since AFS cheats.

# for the convenience of &wanted calls, including -eval statements:
use vars qw/*name *dir *prune/;
*name   = *File::Find::name;
*dir    = *File::Find::dir;
*prune  = *File::Find::prune;

sub wanted;
sub doexec ($@);


use Cwd ();
my $cwd = Cwd::cwd();


# Traverse desired filesystems
File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, 'find', '/tmp');
exit;


sub wanted {
    /^.*.*\z/s &&
    doexec(0, '/tmp/rename.pl');
}


sub doexec ($@) {
    my $ok = shift;
    my @command = @_; # copy so we don't try to s/// aliases to constants
    for my $word (@command)
        { $word =~ s#{}#$name#g }
    if ($ok) {
        my $old = select(STDOUT);
        $| = 1;
        print "@command";
        select($old);
        return 0 unless <STDIN> =~ /^y/;
    }
    chdir $cwd; #sigh
    system @command;
    chdir $File::Find::dir;
    return !$?;
}
```

Since your `doexec` is just a Perl script, you could replace that whole subroutine with your Perl code.